# Fastest way to remotely store and retrieve 300 short time series as pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, feather, arctic

I have an array with around 300 Pandas time series, each one with no more than 6 columns and no more than 10.000 rows.

I need to store these in a separate persistent machine that I can access from other machines. Other machines will read this data very frequentely, and I need this reading to be **as fast possible**.

Initially, I was storing each row as a PostgreSQL row.

Then I switched to [arctic](https://github.com/manahl/arctic), where the performance boost is really impressive if I use threading:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
p = ThreadPool(300)

def read(i):
    return library.read(str(i)).data


dataframes = p.starmap(read, [0,1,2,3...])
```

I've published benchmarks here: https://github.com/manahl/arctic/issues/814

Arctic is based on MongoDB, where dataframes are pickled and then stored and retrieved with a unique key.

With this, I can load my dataframes in 3 seconds from an Atlas free-tier MongoDB instance.

Is there any way this can be done even faster?

Are solutions like Feather and Parquet meant to be stored on filesystem only? If yes, how can I share this filesystem remotely without impacting reading performance? What if I store the pickled dataframe in Postgres, would that be a bad idea?

I've researched a lot of different solutions but they all focus on the size of a single dataframe rather than the quantity of separate ones. My dataframes are relatively small but they're a lot and I need to read all of them, many times.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still interested in benchmarking this problem, it could be worth trying out [ArcticDB](https://github.com/man-group/ArcticDB). This is a revamped version of [Arctic](https://github.com/man-group/arctic) which includes additional features and a faster C++ data-processing engine. The Python API is very similar to Arctic.

In particular, for this problem there is a method [`lib.read_batch`](https://docs.arcticdb.io/latest/api/library/#arcticdb.version_store.library.Library.read_batch) which takes full advantage of C++ concurrency, and will adapt the number of worker threads to the number of available cores on your machine.

Unfortunately Mongo isn't officially supported by ArcticDB yet, but development is underway. There are lots of other backends you can try though, e.g. in-memory, LMDB, S3, and Azure.